# What is the difference between access and search in array?

Tags: algorithm, data-structures

While studying data structure and algorithm, i come across these two term simultaneously, but i am unable to differentiate between access and search. For example time complexity of array include access time of O(1) while search O(n).

Comment: It might be helpful to give more context in your example.  Accessing an element in an array is a constant time operation, which searching through an array is a linear operation.

Comment: Access is usually linked to *position* in array. Search is usually linked to *value of some object*. Therefor Tim is right. You should add some more context.

Answer (score 18):

Let's imagine a street, we'll call this List Street. On list street, there are houses. The Address of the first house is 101 List Street. The address of the second house is 102 List Street. So on and so forth.

Let's say that we know that our friend Element lives at the 4th house on List Street, well then we **know** that Element must live at 104 List Street. We can immediately access their house, because we know exactly where it is on the street. We only need to *access* 1 house in order to find Element.

But what if we didn't know what house Element lived in? We would have to knock on the door of each house and ask if Element lives there. In this case, we would need to access 4 houses until we got to 104 List Street to find Element.

The same idea applies to arrays. An array stores data types. Each data type is of the same size, for example an `int` is usually 4 bytes. If an `int` array starts at memory address `0x0001` and we wanted to access any element, it takes the same amount of time to access `array[2]` as it does `array[102]` as it does `array[9999]`. Because we know the starting address, and we know the size of each data type, we can immediately jump to that location in memory. O(1)

However, if you're trying to *search* for a specific element, then you need to access each element and test if it's the element you're looking for, until you reach the desired element. For an array with 5 elements, you might have to search 5 times. O(5). For an array with 900 elements, you might have to search 900 times until you find your desired element. O(900). For an array with `n` elements, you would search `n` times. O(n)

Comment: what about access & search in trees?

Answer (score 11):

Access: get A[i] element value
Search: find whether some value exists in array (and get it's index)

Answer (score 0):

Accessing an element of an array means that you know its index and using that you specify which element you want to load. This operation has a complexity of **O(1)**, since the location in memory must be calculated to achieve this purpose and the calculation takes the same amount of time regardless of index (a small amount of time).

Searching an element means that you do not know where it is and (in this case) sequentially search for it in the array. The best case is that the very first element is the one you are searching for, rendering further searches pointless, but that is highly improbable. The worst case is that the very last element you look at is the one you are searching for, which would mean that you have to go through all n (**O(n)** complexity) elements of the array to reach the one you search for. Realistically, if n->infinity, then it is highly unprobable that the very first or the very last element is the one you are searching for, but it is probable that you will have to look sequentially a lot of elements. This "lot" proportionally increases with the amount of elements, hence this is a complexity of **O(n)**, or linear complexity, because a line is a function of

**f(x) = a * x + b**

**f'(x) = a**

In this case a = 1, but when we calculate complexity, we do not really care whether it is 1 or 2. We care about its derivative, which is a constant. While the derivative of

**g(x) = a**

is

**g'(x) = 0**

Answer (score 0):

Let's think of an analogy:

There is `N` mailboxes in a row and one of them is yours. Each mailbox has its owner name on it.

Surely **you know where it is**, so you do not need to really stop and look at each of the mailbox to get to your mailbox. **This is access**.

---

Now a new postman come around and ask you do you know which is **Simon's mailbox**?

"What? Who the hash is Simon?" You said, "I don't know, but I can **find** with you together"

As the mailboxes have no specific order like ordered by owner's name, you can just access them one by one to check if it belongs to Simon's. Now the **whole process is searching**.

---

Now, for getting to your own mailbox, you only do ONE access, right? And this does not change even when the number of mailboxes `N` changed! So it is `O(1)`

But for searching, the worst case is there is **NO Simon's mailbox** and you can only know this AFTER access ALL  mailboxes, which is `N` access. So it is `O(N)`